# control a toggle by a button click

Tags: processing, control-p5

i needed to create a gui where a toggle would be ON when we click on a specified button , the problem is i cant find the right command to do so , here is an example of how i added my toggle :

```
cp5.addToggle("condenseur")
     .setPosition(700,585)
     .setSize(70,70)
     .setValue(false)
     .setLabelVisible(false);
```

and here is the function (the button click) where i want it to return a char AND change the toggle state (makes it ON)
void marche(){
port.write('a');

i tried to use setValue() or condensateur = true but none worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses two buttons to toggle a cp5 toggle button.  Reference: https://www.kasperkamperman.com/blog/processing-code/controlp5-library-example2/

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;

void setup() {
  size(400, 300);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  cp5.addToggle("toggle")
    .setPosition(200, 90)
    .setSize(70, 70)
    .setValue(false)
    .setLabelVisible(false)
    ;

  cp5.addButton("on")
    .setValue(0)
    .setPosition(50, 100)
    .setSize(50, 19)
    ;

  cp5.addButton("off")
    .setValue(0)
    .setPosition(120, 100)
    .setSize(50, 19)
    ;
}

void draw() {
}

void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {

  if (theEvent.isController()) {
    print("control event from : " + theEvent.getController().getName());
    println(", value : " + theEvent.getController().getValue());

    if (theEvent.getController().getName()=="on") {
      cp5.getController("toggle").setValue(1);
    }

    if (theEvent.getController().getName()=="off") {
      cp5.getController("toggle").setValue(0);
    }
  }
}
```